# Styles in ASP.NET Core and @angular/cli

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-core, angular-cli

We run several @angular/cli apps with ASP.NET Core, each with their own route/controller/view. Our layout depends on bootstrap, and so do several of our apps. This presents a few problems.

If we build our @angular/cli apps with the styles in, then at runtime we have two copies of bootstrap. If we remove the layout's copy of bootstrap, it will function using the app's copy, but not without some lag and flashing. If we go the other way, it's just a pain to develop with the cli and then remove the styles from angular-cli.json before building.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Very late to the party, but I would use the `assets` folder in the cli folder structure.
You can put there the `Bootstrap` stylesheet and reference it (in index.html) with a link, exactly in the same way you're going to reference it from the MVC views.